# Textlocal API sends SMS only to one user and not to others

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am doing attendance app that stores the attendance for students and I want to send their Attendance percentage to their parents occasionally. So the problem is when I retrieve all students name, percentage, phone number from firebase database and using Textlocal API to send SMS to them, it is sending SMS only to the one user and for remaining users not sending. I am glad if anyone help me. Thanks in advance.

```
DatabaseReference databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Students");
                    databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for (final DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                                        Student student=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Student.class);

                                        final String name=student.getName();
                                        final String phone=student.getPhone();
                                        final String reg=student.getReg();

                                        DatabaseReference databaseReference1=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Count");
                                        databaseReference1.child(reg).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                                                    int presentPeriods=dataSnapshot.getValue(int.class);
                                                    int totalPeriods=totalWorkingDays*7;
                                                    float percent=(float)presentPeriods/(float)totalPeriods*100;
                                                    int nPrecent=(int)percent;
                                                    sendSMS(name,phone,reg,nPrecent);
                                                }
                                                else {
                                                    int percent=0;
                                                    sendSMS(name,phone,reg,percent);
                                                }
                                            }

                                            @Override
                                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                            }
                                        });



                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

private void sendSMS(String name, String phone, String reg, int percent) {
    if (networkAvailable()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Sending alerts...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println("To: "+phone.replace("+91","")+" / "+"Your ward, "+name+" with Register Number "+reg.replace("R","")+" is having Attendance percentage of "+percent+" as on "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date()));
        String out="Your ward, "+name+" with Register Number "+reg.replace("R","")+" is having Attendance percentage of "+percent+" as on "+new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
        String toNumber=phone.replace("+91","");


        try {
            // Construct data
            String apiKey = "apikey=" + "XXXXXXXXXXX";
            String message = "&message=" + out;
            String sender = "&sender=" + "TXTLCL";
            String numbers = "&numbers=" + toNumber;

            // Send data
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("https://api.textlocal.in/send/?").openConnection();
            String data = apiKey + numbers + message + sender;
            conn.setDoOutput(true);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(data.length()));
            conn.getOutputStream().write(data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
            final StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
            String line;
            while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(line);
            }
            rd.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, stringBuffer.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error SMS "+e);
            Toast.makeText(this,"Error: "+e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you checked size of DataSnapshot.

Comment: yes. datasnapshot giving five set of student's data. SMS is sending to only last student and for the first four students not sending.

Comment: you need to debug your app with debugger and breakpoints to see which code is being called with which values, etc.

Comment: Have you solved the issue? If not, please add the database structure and please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

When `databaseReference1.child(reg).addListenerForSingleValueEvent()` is triggered, the `phone` is already set to last `student` object value. So whenever databaseReference1 listener is triggered, sms will be sent to last phone value in your list.

Modify your logic accordingly.

Comment: I think it can solve my problem. Can you please tell me clearly?? I don't understand it. Thanks...